# How to get the data between the hours(10AM to 11 AM) in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to get the data between the hour's timestamp in mongodb.

I have these type of documents.

```
{ 
  _id: 1,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:00:00Z"
  "energy": 2333
},
{ 
  _id: 2,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:10:00Z"
  "energy": 2340
},
{ 
  _id: 3,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:30:00Z"
  "energy": 2349
},
{ 
  _id: 4,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:40:00Z"
  "energy": 2355
},
{ 
  _id: 5,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:50:00Z"
  "energy": 2360
},
{ 
  _id: 6,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z"
  "energy": 2370
}
```

I want merge the data from 10:00AM to 11:00 AM and I have wrote a query but its taking from 10:00 AM to 10:50 AM document fields, its not taking 11:00 AM document.

```
{
"$project": {"energy": 1,"dateparts": {"$dateToParts": {"date": "$timestamp}}}},
"$group": {"activeEnergy": {$push: {"minute":"$dateparts.minute", "energy": "$activeEnergy"}}
}
```

this query Output:

```
(
{
    "_id": {
              year: 2023
              month: 5
              day: 15
              hour: 10
          }
    "activeEnergy": [
           { minute: 0, energy: 2333},
           { minute: 10, energy: 2340},
           { minute: 30, energy: 2349},
           { minute: 40, energy: 2355},
           { minute: 50, energy: 2360},
})
```

But its not taking from 10:50 to 11:00  documents

```
{ minute: , energy: 2370},
```

Require Output:

```
(
{
    "_id": {
              year: 2023
              month: 5
              day: 15
              hour: 10
          }
    "activeEnergy": [
           { minute: 0, energy: 2333},
           { minute: 10, energy: 2340},
           { minute: 30, energy: 2349},
           { minute: 40, energy: 2355},
           { minute: 50, energy: 2360}
           { minute: 59, energy: 2370},
})
```

Can you please help on this issue, How to get last minutes of the data in this scenario.

Comment: Apart from syntax error in your query, the query does not match the output you show. Please provide valid code.

Comment: There is no data for minute 59, how can you expect any result from this time?

Comment: Sorry, 

Actually every 15 min one document will be added in my collection. Suppose: 1st doc: 10:00 2nd doc: 10:15 3rd doc: 10:30 4th doc: 10:45 5th doc: 11:00 your query is taking documents from 10:00 to 10:45 data value, what are energy getting from 10:45 to 11:00 that data will save in 11:00 documents. this document is missed, I need that data also.. Can you please help on this

Answer (score 1):

You can get your required output by this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-05-15T10:00:00Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2023-05-15T11:00:00Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      year: { $year: "$timestamp" },
      month: { $month: "$timestamp" },
      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" },
      hour: { $hour: "$timestamp" },
      minute: { $minute: "$timestamp" },
      energy: "$energy"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$year",
        month: "$month",
        day: "$day",
        hour: "$hour"
      },
      activeEnergy: {
        $push: {
          minute: "$minute",
          energy: "$energy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Hazik Arshad for shared.

I tried this way but its not getting last value, Actually every 15 min one document will be added in my collection.

Suppose:
         1st doc: 10:00
         2nd doc: 10:15
         3rd doc: 10:30
         4th doc: 10:45
         5th doc: 11:00

your query is taking documents from 10:00 to 10:45 data value, what are energy getting from 10:45 to 11:00 that data will save in 11:00 documents. this document is missed,

 I need that  data also.. Can you please help on this.