# How to subtract the field value in between timestamp in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know how to subtract the field values with help of timestamp in mongodb.

```
{ 
  _id: 1,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:00:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2333
},
{ 
  _id: 2,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:10:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2340
},
{ 
  _id: 3,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:30:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2349
},
{ 
  _id: 4,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:40:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2355
},
{ 
  _id: 5,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:50:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2360
},
{ 
  _id: 6,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z"
  "code": "abc",
  "energy": 2370
},
{ 
  _id: 7,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:00:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3455
},
{ 
  _id: 8,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:10:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3460
},
{ 
  _id: 9,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:30:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3470
},
{ 
  _id: 10,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:40:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3480
},
{ 
  _id: 11,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:50:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3490
},
{ 
  _id: 12,
  "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z"
  "code": "def",
  "energy": 3500
}
```

I need to subtract the first energy field in hour(11:00) and first energy field value in hour(10:00)

Same like
First energy field in hour(12:00) and first energy field value in hour(11:00)
First energy field in hour(13:00) and first energy field value in hour(12:00)
First energy field in hour(14:00) and first energy field value in hour(13:00)

Expected output:

{
"timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z",
"code": "abc",
"energy": 37
},
{
"timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z",
"code": "def",
"energy": 45
}

Comment: The same as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259526/how-to-get-the-data-between-the-hours10am-to-11-am-in-mongodb). Your sample data is rather poor to demonstrate your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {timestamp: 1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {$dateTrunc: {date: "$timestamp", unit: "hour"}},
      energy: {$first: "$energy"}
  }},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {_id: 1},
      output: {prevEnergy: {
          $push: "$energy",
          window: {documents: [-1, 0]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {"prevEnergy.1": {$exists: true}}},
  {$project: {deltaFromPrev: {$subtract: [{$last: "$prevEnergy"}, {$first: "$prevEnergy"}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e8dyDudD1FB)

**UPDATE:**
For the updated question use:
[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6Rsv_lyORPt)

Comment: Thank you Serok, I got correct output for using these query, but this query is taking one code only, I have updated the question please check  and help on this.

Comment: Added an update on the end of the answer