# subtract the field value in between timestamp in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to know how to subtract the field values with help of timestamp in mongodb.

''{ _id: 1, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:00:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2333 }, { _id: 2, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:10:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2334 }, { _id: 3, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:30:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2349 }, { _id: 4, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:40:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2355 }, { _id: 5, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:50:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2360 }, { _id: 6, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z" "code": "abc", "energy": 2370 }, { _id: 7, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:00:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3455 }, { _id: 8, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:10:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3460 }, { _id: 9, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:30:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3470 }, { _id: 10, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:40:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3480 }, { _id: 11, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T10:50:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3490 }, { _id: 12, "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z" "code": "def", "energy": 3500 }''

I need to subtract the first energy field in hour(11:00) and first energy field value in hour(10:00)

Same like First energy field in hour(12:00) and first energy field value in hour(11:00) First energy field in hour(13:00) and first energy field value in hour(12:00) First energy field in hour(14:00) and first energy field value in hour(13:00)

I tried many ways but I didn't get exact output.

Expected output:

{ "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z", "code": "abc", "energy": 37 }, { "timestamp": "2023-05-15T11:00:00Z", "code": "def", "energy": 45 }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract the field value in between timestamp in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76260797/how-to-subtract-the-field-value-in-between-timestamp-in-mongodb)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.